# Edit button and allowing some users to edit subtype

Tags: drupal, css, contact-types

I've removed the main Edit button from the top of the contact record (using CSS) because it confuses people.

Almost everything can be edited by hovering over it, with the exception of contact subtype and external ID.

We don't edit external IDs but some people need to be able to change contact subtypes.

The people who edit subtypes could easily cope with the "global" edit button being there without getting confused.

Can anyone suggest a way of showing / hiding the edit button by role or group? Or any other solution to allow some users to edit subtypes, while not showing the global edit button to everyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What CMS are you using?

In Drupal, an easy way to do this would be to add a Block, shown conditionally by role, containing your css.